# Using str_view with a list of words in R

Tags: r, string, view, extract, stringr

I want to use `str_view` from stringr in R to find all the words that start with "y" and all the words that end with "x." I have a list of words generated by Corpora, but whenever I launch the code, it returns a blank view.

```
Common_words<-corpora("words/common")

#start with y
start_with_y <- str_view(Common_words, "^[y]", match = TRUE)
start_with_y

#finish with x
str_view(Common_words, "$[x]", match = TRUE)
```

Also, I would like to find the words that are only 3 letters long, but no
ideas so far.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by a minimal complete verifiable example?

Comment: That link explains it? :) How about `str_view(s, '^y(.)*x$')`

Comment: What is `Common_words`? Please provide data to test and state the expected output. From what you say, you need `str_extract_all(common_words, "\\b(y\\w*|\\w*x)\\b")`

Comment: Common words is just the name that I am assigning to the list of generated (common) words, it is generated by the corpora package,  I didn't include it as it is quite long. The expected output would either be the list highlighting the words that start with y, finish with x or are 3 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is not about programming with **stringr** but learning some regex.  Here are some sites I have found useful for learning:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html
- http://www.rexegg.com/
- https://www.debuggex.com/

Here the `\\w` or short hand class for word characters (i.e., `[A-Za-z0-9_]`) is useful with quantifiers (`+` and `{3}` in these 2 cases).  PS here I use **stringi** because **stringr** is using that in the backend anyway.  Just skipping the middle man.

```
x <- c("I like yax because the rock to the max!", 
    "I yonx & yix to pick up stix.")

library(stringi)

stri_extract_all_regex(x, 'y\\w+x')
stri_extract_all_regex(x, '\\b\\w{3}\\b')

## > stri_extract_all_regex(x, 'y\\w+x')
## [[1]]
## [1] "yax"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "yonx" "yix" 


## > stri_extract_all_regex(x, '\\b\\w{3}\\b')
## [[1]]
## [1] "yax" "the" "the" "max"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "yix"
```

**EDIT**  Seems like these may be of use too:

```
## Just y starting words
stri_extract_all_regex(x, 'y\\w+\\b')

## Just x ending words
stri_extract_all_regex(x, 'y\\w+x')

## Words with n or more characters
stri_extract_all_regex(x, '\\b\\w{4,}\\b')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great !

Comment: Hi again, do you know how, using this same type of code, I could specify that I want all words above 6 letters other than simply repeating the code for 6,7, 8 etc? Thanks!

Comment: Sure use a open ended quantifier `'\\b\\w{6,}\\b'`.  Spend a bit of time with the tutorials I linked to.  They're well worth the time.

Comment: Cheers! yeah I've had a quick look, I'll see them more in detail soon !